# MySQL, check if foreign key assigned to any table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table `files`
Also, I have more that 100 tables where I use relation/foreign key as `file_id`

How can I get all `files` with non-existing relations (it means that file not attached to any table)?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you want to find all the tables that don't have `FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files (file_id)`? Or do you mean rows in `files` that aren't referenced from any of the other tables? Please show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you are looking for all entries in table `files` where there is no entry in any of the other tables (xyz1, xyz2, xyz3) referencing that said file. In the following example, your want files 2 and 4 as a result, right?

## `files`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

## `xyz1`

| id | file_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

## `xyz2`

| id | file_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

## `xyz3`

| id | file_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

The not so intelligent approach. Build up an ugly statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM files f WHERE

NOT EXISTS (SELECT file_id FROM xyz1 WHERE f.id = xyz1.file_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT file_id FROM xyz2 WHERE f.id = xyz2.file_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT file_id FROM xyz3 WHERE f.id = xyz3.file_id)
;
```

To easily get the 100 `AND NOT EXISTS` lines, get all table names having a field named `file_id` and concatenate them into SQL lines (replace `your_database_name` with your actual database name):

```
SELECT CONCAT('AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT file_id FROM ', TABLE_NAME, ' WHERE f.id = ', TABLE_NAME, '.file_id)')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'file_id';
```

Copy the query result, add the lines to the first SQL query above, run it and you should have the desired files.

Comment: You can run the query automatically by writing a stored procedure that uses `PREPARE` to generate dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, and I agree that you should, especially if this is needed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I am usually do like this in bash(maybe possible to make SQL, but I am not sure which table)

```
table_names=`echo "show tables"|mysql database_name -q -s|grep -v "show tables"`
for table in $table_names
do
  echo $table
  mysqldump database_name $table |grep file_id
done;
```

And you will see anything related to file_id in each one table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE referenced_table_schema = 'your database name'
  AND referenced_table_name = 'files';
```

[The INFORMATION_SCHEMA KEY_COLUMN_USAGE Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-key-column-usage-table.html)